# How to flush fmt output in debug mode?

Tags: c++, io, output, fmt

I'm experimenting with [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) and I do get output from code below

```
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::crimson) | fmt::emphasis::bold,
             "Hello, {}!\n", "world");
  fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::floral_white) | bg(fmt::color::slate_gray) |
             fmt::emphasis::underline, "Hello, {}!\n", "???");
  fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::steel_blue) | fmt::emphasis::italic,
             "Hello, {}!\n", "??");
}
```

However it seems to happen after program exits. If I step over each line in debug mode there is no output?

Perhaps it should flush?

I tried `fflush(stdout);` unsuccessfuly.

The following seems to help. With it I get the prints with sleep in the middle. However still no print during debug while stepping in each line.

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

https://thomas.trocha.com/blog/qt-creator--make-stdout-work-in-application-output-view/

```
int main() {

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::crimson) | fmt::emphasis::bold,
                   "Hello, {}!\n", "world");

    qDebug() << "1";
    QThread::msleep(2000);
    qDebug() << "2";

    fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::floral_white) | bg(fmt::color::slate_gray) |
               fmt::emphasis::underline, "Hello, {}!\n", "???");

    QThread::msleep(2000);

    fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::steel_blue) | fmt::emphasis::italic,
               "Hello, {}!\n", "??");
}
```

Comment: Where are you viewing your program output? Is it possible that that is buffering the output?

Comment: What happens if you enclose those statements into a local scope block?

Comment: @AlanBirtles QtCreator application output panel. What's buffering output?

Comment: Try just putting a sleep statement between the prints and run the program normally in a terminal and see if they're printed correctly

Comment: With the sleep in the middle it still prints only at the end

Comment: Enclose those statements into a local scope block does not change anything.

Comment: Probably it's platform specific question. Could you elaborate on your OS, distro and compiler, ide and how did you compile your first mre (the one without Qt)?

Comment: I use gcc9.3, gdb9.2, fmt 8.1.1 and `fflush(stdout)` on ubuntu20 and it just works. So the problem might be QtCreator itself.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 64bits with ms compiler (16.11.31702.278 and cdb 10.0.17763.132, vs 2019) but I use QtCreator, with fmt-7.1.3 installed from vcpkg. To compile it I hit build on QtCreator. Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: It'd be better if you include the QtCreator and Qt version.

Comment: I'll suggest try to use visual studio and its debugger to check if it's working.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `fmt::print`, you could use `fmt::format` and send that to `std::cout` and use `std::flush`:

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << fmt::format(fg(fmt::color::crimson) | fmt::emphasis::bold,
             "Hello, {}!\n", "world") << std::flush;

  std::cout << fmt::format(fg(fmt::color::floral_white) | bg(fmt::color::slate_gray) |
             fmt::emphasis::underline, "Hello, {}!\n", "???") << std::flush;
             
  std::cout << fmt::format(fg(fmt::color::steel_blue) | fmt::emphasis::italic,
             "Hello, {}!\n", "??")  << std::flush;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stderr` to print the content immediately.

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <cstdio> // ::stderr

int main() {
  fmt::print(stderr, "Print right away");
}
```

#### Description

fmt uses buffered output. It comes with [its own buffer class](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#system-apis).
It outputs to `stdout`, I'm not sure about `qDebug` but from the name it doesn't use `stdout`.

Make sure to check the "[Run in terminal](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#launching-the-debugger-in-different-modes)" check box in Compiler Explorer.
In any case: you can change the output stream used by `fmt::print` by passing a `std::FILE*` as the first argument.

```cpp
fmt::print(stderr, "This is printed first");
std::cerr << "This is printed second.";
std::cout << "When this is printed is implementation defined.";
std::clog << "Unlike std::cerr and std::cin, std::clog will not flush std::cout.";
```

Detailed example on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:73,endLineNumber:28,positionColumn:73,positionLineNumber:28,selectionStartColumn:73,selectionStartLineNumber:28,startColumn:73,startLineNumber:28),source:%27%23include+%3Cfmt/color.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfmt/core.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfmt/format.h%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Cchrono%3E++++//+operator+%22%22ms%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E++++//+setbuf%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E++//+cout,+clog%0A%23include+%3Cthread%3E++++//+this_thread::sleep_for%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++using+namespace+std%3B%0A++setbuf(stdout,+nullptr)%3B%0A%0A++fmt::print(stderr,+fg(fmt::color::crimson)+%7C+fmt::emphasis::bold,%0A+++++++++++++%22Hello,+%7B%7D!!%5Cn%22,+%22world%22)%3B%0A%0A++clog+%3C%3C+%221%22%3B++//+unbuffered,+to+stderr%0A++this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms)%3B%0A++clog+%3C%3C+%222%22%3B%0A%0A++fmt::print(+fg(fmt::color::floral_white)+%7C+bg(fmt::color::slate_gray)%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+fmt::emphasis::underline,%0A+++++++++++++%22Hello,+%7B%7D!!%5Cn%22,+%22%3F%3F%3F%22)%3B++//+buffered+to+stdout%0A%0A++this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms)%3B%0A++cerr+%3C%3C+%22%5Cncerr+is+unbuffered+by+default.+It+doesn!%27t+sync+with+stdout.%5Cn%22%3B%0A++cout+%3C%3C+%22%5Cncout+is+buffered+by+default.+It+syncs+with+stdout.%5Cn%22%3B%0A++fmt::print(stdout,+fg(fmt::color::steel_blue)+%7C+fmt::emphasis::italic,%0A+++++++++++++%22Hello,+%7B%7D!!%5Cn%22,+%22%3F%3F%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:63.96517079705292,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:%27700%27)),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:36.03482920294708,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)
I'm not aware of any way to flush the fmt print buffer manually. I'm looking into it.

#### I looked into it (2024-03-26 edit)

So… There's no way (I know off) to sync `stdout` with `stderr`.
However,

> Output to stderr via std::cerr flushes out the pending output on std::cout, while output to stderr via std::clog does not.
> (cf: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr#Example))

Finally,

> fmt does not take the decision to buffer or not the output, it just forwards the content to the libc.
>
> You can turn off buffering with:

```cpp
setbuf(stdout, nullptr);
// Strictly equivalent to: setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
```

Paraphrasing [kiwixz](https://github.com/kiwixz)'s answer on an [issue about this on the fmt repo](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2134#issuecomment-1902644467).

Comment: Special thanks to [Amin Ya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7910299/amin-ya) for [their edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72876540/2).